# Error partial template specialization at compile GCC, but not MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, syntax-error

**The following code, compiles fine MSVC, but when building GCC provides a lot of errors:**

```
#define FORCE_INLINE inline
#define CREF(A) const A&

template <class F>
class RDOFunCalcStd: public RDOFunCalc
{
...
template <class T>
FORCE_INLINE T getParam(CREF(LPRDORuntime) pRuntime, ruint paramNumber);

template <>
FORCE_INLINE double getParam<double>(CREF(LPRDORuntime) pRuntime, ruint paramNumber)
{
    return pRuntime->getFuncArgument(paramNumber).getDouble();
}

template <>
FORCE_INLINE int getParam<int>(CREF(LPRDORuntime) pRuntime, ruint paramNumber)
{
    return pRuntime->getFuncArgument(paramNumber).getInt();
}
...
};
```

**Errors list:**

> error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class rdoRuntime::RDOFunCalcStd’
>
> error: template-id ‘getParam’ in declaration of primary template
>
> error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class rdoRuntime::RDOFunCalcStd’
>
> error: template-id ‘getParam’ in declaration of primary template
>
> error: ‘int rdoRuntime::RDOFunCalcStd::getParam(const rdoRuntime::LPRDORuntime&, ruint)’ cannot be overloaded
>
> error: with ‘double rdoRuntime::RDOFunCalcStd::getParam(const rdoRuntime::LPRDORuntime&, ruint)’

**What should be done to solve the error?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this

[Article from Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

It explained why. To be short, C++ does not support function template specialization.